# Name for points with same value in a periodic function

Tags: periodic-functions

I'm looking for a name to describe the points of the same value of a periodic function -- you draw a horizontal line across a periodic function and you get a set of values.

That is, a *name* for _all $x$ points where $\sin(x)=0$, for example.  That would be the set of points $x=n\pi, n \in \mathbb{I}$.  But is there a *name* to describe this set -- e.g. all the "isopoints" of $\sin(x)$ for a given value of $\sin(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only name is just [the fiber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28mathematics%29) (or levelset or preimage of a point).

Comment: Another name I have encountered is "level set" (at least for real-valued functions).

Comment: @DanielFischer i'm silly, i didn't actually read the wiki page except enough to verify that it was the right one, and it lists level set and preimage as other names